# Set, sequence, in-between?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I just started studying discrete mathematics and although I understand the formal differences between sets and sequences (sets as unordered collections of distinct elements, sequences as ordered collections with possibly identical elements), I do not understand the rationale behind defining them like that.

How are they useful the way they are?

Would defining something in-between, say an ordered collection of distinct
elements, have its perks as well? Could that be used in any way?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your concerns are,  are you asking what are the sequences useful for?

Comment: Sometime we care about order other times we do not

Answer (score 1):

When mathematicians solve problems they often invent concepts that help, and provide formal definitions. When students learn mathematics they often see the formal definitions before the problems that prompted them, and ask why, as you do.

You will encounter some problems in your discrete mathematics class that are best modeled by sets, some best modeled by sequences. You usually then want to count them.

Perhaps you'll stumble on a problem that you want to model with the "in between" structure you've invented (which resembles a permutation). If it turns out to be generally useful it will get its own name.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions you gave is very rough, I will use Naive Set theory rather than ZFC as that will only make things more convoluted.

> A set is a collection of distinct objects

This is a fairly straightforward view of what a set is. Not entirily true anymore as it will inevitably lead to contradictions but for now we will ignore that issue in favour of the essence of what a set is. Think of yourself as a car salesman and you ask yourself the question "What car models do I have?", if you have 3 Volvos of the same model doesn't matter, they still count as a single model. Which order we decide to put them also doesn't matter as it's the models that matters, not any order we put them in. That is in some way capturing what we see set as.

Your idea of a sequence is a bit "bare bone" to say so I'll give a better definition.

> Let $A$ be a given set, then a sequence of elements in $A$ is a function $f:\Bbb N\to A$

This works as the only distinction is notational. For functions we have that $f=g$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$, as such order is suddenly of vital importans. The thing here is of course that a single object can occure more than once. To use the previous analogy it is the case when you ask "What cars can I sell?", if you have 3 Volvos of the same model they can each be sold seperately to give you profit so each one is worthwhile on it's own merit and hence must each be counted once.

Though you can now ask in that analogy "Why does order matter?" Well it can be worthwhile so we care about the lowest first and the highest last. That is entirely our own desire. However there ARE things where an element can occure more htan once, but order does not matter. They are caleld Multisets.

You can also have the one you said without any issue, it just isn't used many times in mathematics.